# Why does my COLD water smell? (City)

Tags: plumbing

I’m trying to figure out a new and sudden smell from my water. The smell is sort of natural gas smelling. It’s very strong. Here is what I know so far:

1. Both hot and cold smell
2. It comes from every fixture in the house.
3. Hot water heater is 2 years old.
4. My city tested it Friday and will get back to me next week.
5. Pipes are copper and house is 17 years old.

I’m desperate at this point. A plumber is coming Tuesday, but I had one over the phone already tell me he wouldn’t be able to diagnose it as he’s already perplexed by the above details.

Comment: Any neighbors that you can ask (a) if they smell the same thing in their water, (b) if you can go their homes and smell their water, (c) if they can come to your home and smell your water? All of that would help determine whether the problem is specific to your home (internal plumbing) or a broader area (city) and/or whether the problem is something you notice but not other people (which would not mean it doesn't exist but may help narrow down the possibilities as to what is going on).

Comment: Thanks! I did ask my neighbors and they said it they didn’t smell anything. I may ask to go inside, though.

Comment: Does your town get it's water from a spring, reservoir, or something else? During the summer, algal blooms are not uncommon in reservoirs and can give the water an undesirable smell and taste, though water treatment should keep it safe.

Does your house have a filter or water softener that might need to be recharged or replaced?

Comment: No softener or filter. Thought now I feel like I should get one installed to see if it fixes it. We get our water from the Duck River.

Comment: Do you feel eye pressure or do your upper teeth hurt?  Plugged up or dripping nose?  You may have a sinus infection.

Comment: What do you use to heat your home ? Gas, Electric

Comment: I use gas to heat.

Answer (score 2):

Could be a Hydrogen Sulfide /  Sulfur Bacteria colony growing somewhere in your plumbing, I've fought those for several years in my house.  The fix is to flush the system with a diluted bleach solution. Since you are drawing water from a river, I assume you have access to the intake.  I DK how feasible this in your case, but what I did was get a NEW garbage can, put a few gallons of bleach in it and filled with water, turned off the main water valve,  then using a small pump, connected it to an outside hose bib that didn't have a check valve on it and let water run at all the faucets until I smelled the bleach. Then shut off the pump and let the system be turned off for a few hours. After turning it back on again, many of the faucets had the grossed black water you can imagine. It takes a few days for the bleach smell to totally go away. I didn't flush the water heater because it would take forever to get rid of the bleach. If you wish to flush the hot water lines, you might want to consider a temp plumbing change at the WH that directly connects the hot and the cold lines. This stuff is trial and error, it's hard to tell where the issue is. There is a municipal water system on the coast here in Western Washington that fought sulfur bacteria infestations for years.

In your case since you have a river intake, ideally it would be best to put the intake into the NEW garbage can with the bleach solution, that way, you'll be treating the entire system. Again, not knowing more about your layout, that may or may not be a practical.

Lastly, if you decide to try the bleach treatment, if you get dark, almost black water when purging the bleach solution, THAT'S SUCCESS! It means you killed the colony.

Comment: I appreciate all the information, it could very well be all of that growing in there. Although, you may have misunderstood when I said the source is from the river. Our city pulls it from the river. I have no way to get to the intake. I live in a suburban neighborhood.

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood, sorry!  I still believe you might have a Sulfur bacteria colony early in your plumbing since it's affecting all faucets, it will be difficult to get to the colony location with the bleach approach if it's between the meter and main supply to the house.   Wish you well.

Comment: 2 questions. 1. Do you think it will show up in the water test? And 2. Do you think a whole house filter would help? We’ve been wanting one anyway.

Comment: If it's outside the house you'll probably need a chlorine injector (or similar disinfectant application) (which is then typically followed by a tank to allow sufficent contact time, and a carbon filter to remove excess chlorine - maintenance of which is an ongoing expense.) As such, one hopes your water supplier will  kill the problem upstream of your house. A normal particulate or carbon filter will not do much for (or be quickly loaded up by the products from) an upstream contaminated pipe.